# What is the best way to manually edit and update data within a large table in MS SQL Server?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql-server

I have a table in MS SQL server which currently has around 800 records and 20 columns.

I want to manually update and add to the information within this table on a frequent basis.

Would exporting the table to Microsoft Excel (and later and re-importing it back to SQL Server) be the best solution for this, or is there another (free) solution?

Please note that I do know how to export the table data from MS SQL Server to Excel, I am just wondering if this is the neatest way to do this.

Comment: Do you have MS Access available? SSMS?

Comment: Yes I have MS Access and SSMS available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your SQL back-end is an MS SQL server you can use the Microsoft [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593) (Express edition linked) to directly query and edit data (amongst many other things).

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express is a free,
>   integrated environment for accessing, configuring, managing,
>   administering, and developing all components of SQL Server, as well as
>   combining a broad group of graphical tools and rich script editors
>   that provide access to SQL Server to developers and administrators of
>   all skill levels.

Answer (score 1):

More simply, use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) or MS Access if you have it available.

If you have SQL Server, you have SSMS...

Although, what is the table there for? Does it have other clients using it?

Comment: The table is referenced by a web service to get information about ingredients. Although I won't edit the table on the production server - I can edit it in the test server and then publish it to production later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Many people, my self included, use [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) for MySQL interactions.  It may be too slow for what you need though (one entry at a time kind of thing).  It's completely free and gives direct access to the database.  Even if you don't use if for this I recommend having it available.

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned I actually need to update a lot of data at a time. I should have explained my question better though because I can use SSMS, but it's a bit clunky. I think I'm going to stick with exporting it to Excel (I can then manipulate the data in there - sort, highlight missing entries, etc.) and then re-import it back into MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You've already selected an answer, but I was a fan of [Evolutility](http://evolutility.org/index.aspx) for quick CRUD interfaces. It has support for mass updates and a pleasing UI.